# What is the difference between batch.draw and sprite.draw in LibGDX?

Tags: libgdx, sprite

Both of the methods look similar, but I'm having a hard time understanding when to use these. I just want to know where to use these two, e.g. `sprite.draw(batch)` and `batch.draw(sprite,x,y)`.

Comment: In the context of Libgdx, this is a very specific question, and should not have been closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is for drawing a texture the other is for drawing a sprite.

```
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBach.draw(texture, x,y);
spriteBatch.end();
```

and

```
spriteBatch.begin();
sprite.draw(sprite,x,y);
spriteBatch.end();
```

Link to relevant libgdx wiki: [Spritebatch, Textureregions, and Sprites](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Spritebatch,-Textureregions,-and-Sprites)